# How to authorize snapshots for gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have:

1. Initialized gcloud.

   gcloud init
2. Generated a key for a service account from the IAM console. (web interface)
   -> The service account has "Editor" privileges for my project.
3. Authorized the service account.

   gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file *mykeyfile*

However, when I try to access the snapshots management features:

```
$  gcloud compute snapshots list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.snapshots.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission
```

I can't find anywhere in the documentation specifically how I grant permission to gcloud to allow it to do this.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to not use the default service account, but to create a new one.  I posted this question to the gce forum and got an answer there:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/3QIjjawlqkY

1)  From the GCE web console, create a new service account.
   a)  Give the new account 'Editor' permissions.
   b)  Download the key for the new account.

2)  Authorize the account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file  some_key_file
```

Note:  *The key file may download with spaces in the name.  The gcloud command line does not like spaces, even if you wrap the name with "".  Rename it without spaces and then try the above command.*

3) Make sure the account is selected:

```
gcloud auth list
```

Note:  *If it isn't 'ACTIVE', you can set the service account being used with:*

```
gcloud config set account someaccount@someproject-iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

4) That is it, you should be good to go now.

Comment: Thanks. Same problem for me and the solution helped!